# Smallest solution to system of linear equations

Tags: c, algorithm, distance, linear-algebra

I need to find the smallest number of steps it takes to get between two points in a grid. If you are positioned at the center, and you can only move in 8 directions to the integer points surrounding you, then what's the least number of steps to take to get to a destination point?

I have a solution for this, but it is massively ugly and I'm honestly a bit ashamed of it:

```
/**
 * @details Each point in the graph is a linear combination of these vectors:
 *
 *     [x] = a[0] + b[1] + c[1] + d[ 1]
 *     [y]    [1]    [1]    [0]    [-1]
 *
 *     EQ1: c + b + d == x
 *     EQ2: a + b - d == y
 *
 * Any path can be simplified to involve at most two of these variables, so we
 * can solve the linear equations above with the knowledge that at least two of
 * a, b, c, and d are 0. The sum of the absolute value of the coefficients is
 * the number of steps taken in the grid.
 */
unsigned min_distance(point_t start, point_t goal)
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    int swap, steps;
    int x, y;

    x = goal.x - start.x;
    y = goal.y - start.y;

    /* Possible simple shortcuts */
    if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
        steps = abs(x) + abs(y);

    } else if (abs(x) == abs(y)) {
        steps = abs(y);

    } else {
        b = x, a = y - b;
        steps = abs(a) + abs(b);

        c = x, a = y;
        swap = abs(a) + abs(c);
        if (steps > swap)
            steps = swap;

        d = x, a = y + d;
        swap = abs(a) + abs(d);
        if (steps > swap)
            steps = swap;

        b = y, c = x - b;
        swap = abs(b) + abs(c);
        if (steps > swap)
            steps = swap;

        b = (x + y) / 2, d = b - y;
        swap = abs(b) + abs(d);
        if ((x + y) % 2 == 0 && steps > swap)
            steps = swap;

        d = -y, c = x - d;
        swap = abs(c) + abs(d);
        if (steps > swap)
            steps = swap;
    }

    return steps;
}
```

The comment at the top explains the actual algorithm: represent each valid step as a column vector in a matrix, then find the smallest solution to the resulting system of linear equations.

In this case I saw the best answer would use at most two variables, and solved the equation six times by setting different combinations of the variables to 0. That's too specific! I want to be able to change the rules about which steps are valid and still be able to find the min distance.

EDIT: I realize this is a very poor simple example of what I'm trying to do, because of how easy it is to simplify the problem in this case. The goal is to calculate the number of steps given arbitrary stepping rules. If it the allowed steps instead looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xosBG.png) then I'd start with a different matrix ([0 2 3 4  x; 1 2 0 -4 y]) and find the least solution to a different system of equations (2b + 3c + 4d = x, a + 2b - 4d = y). I'm actually trying to write a procedure that can work with any set of vectors to find the minimum number of steps.

...Any advice or criticism?

Comment: `max(abs(start.x-goal.x), abs(start.y-goal.y))`?

Comment: With more complex step rules, you might want to [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or look into [integer linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) techniques.

Comment: @user2357112 Okay, that does work in this case. I adapted this function from a slightly more convoluted set of rules (vertical and horizontal steps had a distance of 2, diagonal steps were √2) for the question.

Comment: You say you can move in eight directions but then you are saying that you are not able to move in eight directions.  Are you looking for a general solution for any subset of the eight possible directions of motion?

Comment: A general solution given a set of valid vectors of motion, I guess. In one case I have {<0,2> <1,1> <2,0> <1,-1>}, in another I have {<2,3> <2,0> <2,-3>}.
Also, it's 4 vectors for 8 directions, half of them are the same with negative scalars.